# VStack inside ScrollView bottom alignment in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

Currently building a chat application and I need new messages to appear at the bottom of the screen. I also need to have messages aligned to the bottom. However, using VStack inside ScrollView features top alignment by default.

[image: a busy swiftui]

```
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            Spacer()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
            ForEach(notList, id: \.self) { not in
                NotRow(not: not)
                    
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:0, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
        
    }
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: And you want the empty space to be scrollable ?

Comment: I want it to behave like in chat apps: you can do little scrolling but messages return to the bottom.

Answer (score 20):

`ScrollView` does not propose the same height to its children (`VStack` in this case) as it was proposed to it. It just asks for minimal size. The solution is to make its direct child respond with **the minimum height which was proposed to `ScrollView` itself**. We can achieve this by reading the proposed height via `GeometryReader` and setting that as minimum height of the child.

```swift
GeometryReader { reader in
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            /// Spacer() or Color.red will now behave as expected
        }
        .frame(minHeight: reader.size.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution to flipping as the scrollbar is in the expected position. This solution was much needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

A bit late to answer that one but it might help someone else. You could use a good old double rotation trick to achieve the result you want. Other solutions does not work because the maximum size inside a scroll view is undefined as it depends on its child views to compute its own content size.

```
ScrollView {
  VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
      Spacer()
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
      ForEach(notList, id: \.self) { not in
          NotRow(not: not)
      }

  }
  .padding()
  .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
}
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
```

Comment: This will result in the scrollview starting scrolled all the way to the bottom of the content, if the content size is greater than the available space. The better solution is to use a GeometryReader as suggested by @orkhan-alikhanov

Comment: Honestly this is such a poggers solution. I approve of this message

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing a maxHeight in VStack

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  // content here
}
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity) // <- this
```

Comment: Wow, seems kinda inelegant to have to do this. But it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

If you remove `Spacer()` and put it after the closing braces of your `ForEach`, it will fix it. Here is how your updated code will look like:

```
ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
            ForEach(notList, id: \.self) { not in
                NotRow(not: not)

            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:0, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all of your `Alignment.topLeading`s to `Alignment.bottomLeading`